# Exporting KML/ SHP/ EXCEL Files from Google Maps [Android version]

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, android, google

I want to export my pin locations using Google Maps [ Android version] and save the layer as KML /SHP/EXCEL in my phone. Is this feasible using Google Maps or are there any other applications which can support this functionality?

Comment: See https://www.igismap.com/create-save-export-download-kml-file-google-map/

Comment: This is for desktop version.. how will i export point locations from google maps android version